# Why does mocha say my test is passing when it shouldn't?

Tags: node.js, selenium, mocha.js, chai

Currently, I do not understand why the terminal says my test is passing. I have my test set up to fail.

This is the terminal message:

```
  Google
    ✓ Load google search page


  1 passing (22ms)
```

This is my test written with Node JS

```
const assert = require('assert');
const {Builder, By, Key, until} = require('selenium-webdriver');
const suite = require('selenium-webdriver/testing')

var driver = new Builder()
    .forBrowser('chrome')
    .build();

describe('Google', function() {
  it('Load google search page', function() {
driver.get('https://www.foobar.com')
  .then(_ => driver.wait(until.titleIs('Darkness!'), 10000))
  .then(_ => driver.quit());
    });
  });
```

Comment: Not sure, but you are waiting 10s, then exiting cleanly. There is no error whatsoever, you're not expecting anything, so the test is passing. But I may be wrong.

Comment: The test probably exists before the last promise (`driver.quit`) is resolved. Depending on the version of your setup, you may have to use `await` in an `async` function: https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/javascript/index.html

Comment: In other words, as Florent said. Basically you are not waiting for the asynchronous operations to finish and check their results. You are simply returning right away from your function without raising any errors. The errors are not handled automatically, you should assert for them (like the answer of Gregory)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at [documentation](http://chaijs.com/plugins/chai-as-promised/) when you want to make asynchronous tests use the following format :

```
it('should be fulfilled', function (done) {
    promise.should.be.fulfilled.and.notify(done);
});

it('should be rejected', function (done) {
    otherPromise.should.be.rejected.and.notify(done);
});
```

---

Applied to your case :

```
describe('Google', function() {
  it('Load google search page', function(done) {
     driver.get('https://www.foobar.com')
      .then(() => driver.wait(until.titleIs('Darkness!'), 10000))
      .then(() => driver.quit())
      .then(() => done())
      .catch(done);
  });
});
```